# Why \r\n output become \r\r\n using python write to file

Tags: python, windows, newline

When I try to run the following code.

```py
string = ['A', 'B', '\r', '\n', 'C', 'D']
print(''.join(string))
import io
with io.open(r"test.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline='\r\n') as f:
    f.write(''.join(string)+"\r\n")
```

the output to terminal is

```
AB
CD
```

but the output to txt file (using notepad++ to check), it becomes `\r\r\n`
[scr shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLBXh.png)

how could I resolve it? (I don't want to change the input `string`. I want to keep it as `\r\n`)

I have tried to change the newlines, encoding. And search on google, however no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading [the `open` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) about the `newline` argument, it says:

> When writing output to the stream, if *newline* is `None`, any `'\n'` characters written are translated to the system default line separator, [`os.linesep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.linesep). If *newline* is `''` or `'\n'`, no translation takes place. **If *newline* is any of the other legal values, any `'\n'` characters written are translated to the given string.**

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

By using `newline='\r\n'` you have explicitly told the system to translate any single newline `'\n'` into the carriage-return and newline pair `'\r\n'`. If you also write an explicit carriage-return, then you will write two carriage-returns (one from the data you write, one from the newline translation).

Change to either `newline=''` or `newline='\n'` to not do any translations.

Comment: oh I see, I didn't notice that the newline is use to translate. Thank you.